# Problems in connecting to Mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, django, xampp

I am a newbie to Ubuntu Os and Xampp related stuff but has a good knowledge of python and django.I recently shifted from windows where i used wamp to run mysql.I installed Xampp on my ubuntu desktop instead of separately installing Mysql.The problem is that i cannot make python to connect to Mysql server running on localhost.
I have MYSQLdb connector module installed with my python 2.7.4.
Xampp starts fine and i can run SQL by typing `mysql -u root` in the terminal.So as,the django **manage.py** utility shows the database client shell while running the following code:

```
black_perl@ank:~/Desktop/testproject$ python manage.py dbshell
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  

mysql>
```

But when i do :

```
>>> import MySQLdb as m
>>> a=m.connect(user="root",passwd="",db="test_project")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

I cannot find any directory **/var/run/mysqld**. I have my mysql at **/opt/lampp/bin/mysql**.I tried the other solutions as mentioned on the other related questions here on the stackoverflow but no help. Correct me if  i'm wrong somewhere.
Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Can%27t+connect+to+local+MySQL+server+through+socket+%27/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta&channel=sb&gws_rd=cr&ei=XL7kUs2XI4uFrgeKo4GgDQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you missed `host`, `port` argument.

Arguments to `MySQLdb.connect` should match `DATABASES` in `settings.py`.

For example, assuming following is in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test_project',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret',
        'HOST': '192.168.0.1',
        'PORT': 1234,
    }
}
```

`connect(..)` should read as:

```
import MySQLdb
connection = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', passwd='secret', db='test_project',
                             host='192.168.0.1', port=1234)
```

Comment: I know that the connect function takes two keyword arguments host and port but the real problem was that i had set the host to `localhost` which works on windows but not working here,don't know why.Now i pointed it to `127.0.0.1` , it is working nicely.But, thanks for pointing out once again.