# mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql

I installed (on Ubuntu 13) MYSQL using

`sudo apt-get install mysql`

But after running

`mysql -u root -p`

and entering the password it gives the error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Please guide...

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)

Comment: sometimes I have had problems connecting with socket file, try with `mysql -uroot -p -h 127.0.0.1` or `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: another thing you can check is `mysqladmin variables | grep -i socket`

Comment: It again gives the same error..

Comment: Check if the service is even running, `ps aux | grep mysql`

Answer (score 10):

Problem:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

Solution:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by stopping the apache server first and restarting the mysql server

1. sudo service apache2 stop
2. sudo service mysql stop
3. sudo service mysql start
4. sudo service apache2 start

Comment: After changing owner for `/var/lib/mysql` and later reverting it to `mysql`, nothing worked. This fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

> Hope this can help you
>   (Env: docker ubuntu16.04 container):

i run this code each time restart mysql server, it work for me:

```
  sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld
  sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: Can you explain why that solves the problem? Why should one disable permission checks? Why not start the deamon the usual way?

Comment: I had to upgrade old version, hope it can solve your problem

Comment: This gets even worse: why do you change the file permissions **on each restart**?

Comment: actually, my environment is base on MySQL developed on docker images, it needs to change the file permissions for Non-root user before start MySQL Daemon.

Comment: can u share your situation(system,env,mysql version ...) or error log, maybe i can give you some advices for that if under my conrol.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that Mysql is installed, still able to reproduce the issue, Look for the file in `sql/my.cnf` file.

Verify that the Socket connection path in that file:

- Location shown in the error is: `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
- Actually location in my.conf file : `/home/user/mysql/tmp/mysqld.sock`

  `home/sql/bin >> mysql -u root -p --socket=/home/user/mysql/tmp/mysqld.sock`

In some version's you may find 'mysql.sock' instead 'mysqld.sock'

Answer (score 1):

*Step 1.* Locate a Unix socket file
On the server host in the command line, run the following command:
**mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -e "select @@socket"**

*Step 2.* Use whatever result that is generated above as path to the socket

```
In the command line, run the following command: **mysql -u root -p -S /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock**
Note: /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock path might be different on your machine, mine was different since I am using Xampp, just whatver the command 'mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -e "select @@socket"' generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but I had same problem today.
It solved by removing current mysql and reinstalling mariadb.
It worked for me.

> sudo apt install mariadb-server

Answer (score -4):

Create one micro instance swap space in Ubuntu

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024
>
> mkswap /swapfile
>
> swapon /swapfile

Comment: Can you explain how this is related to the question after all?