# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in Vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I have a problem with my mysql-server in vagrant. Everytime i restart my vagrant box with 
`vagrant reload` or `vagrant up` i get this confusing error. 
My vagrant box is this one here: `ubuntu/trusty64` from 
[Vagrant-Boxes](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64)
This error has been answered already several times here and at askubuntu. 
but i want to know why only this code works for me:

```
su - mysql -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

the code is from the file `mysql*` at `/etc/init.d/mysql`.
can anyone explain what the code means?

all this answeres did **not** help me for explanation from here:

[mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290519/mysql-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-v) 
[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861733/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run) 
[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means the connection to the server failed, and the root cause is that the `MySQL` server is not running, most likely because it was not started.

You need to make sure the machine startup scripts do start `MySQL`, in the proper order (the server before clients connections to it), and be sure to wait for the startup to actually complete.

The following script

```
su - mysql -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

does start the MySQL server.

What it does is:

1. Log in as the mysql user (`su - mysql`)
2. Execute a shell (`-s /bin/sh`)
3. Execute a command in this shell (`-c`)
4. The command itself is `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

This command:

1. Starts a MySQL server (`/usr/bin/mysqld_safe`)
2. Redirect the standard output to nowhere (`> /dev/null`)
3. Redirect the standard error to nowhere as well (`2>&1`)
4. And execute the command in the background (`&`)

Comment: but if i normally start my webserver i still have to runt the script from above... can there be something wrong with my vagrant box ?

Answer (score 4):

this work for me:

1. `sudo service mysql stop`
2. `sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql`
3. `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: and it might have been answer, didn't deserve downvote - +1 to compensate