# How can I access PDO in MAMP?

Tags: php, pdo, phpunit

I'm setting up a PDO connection in a test script:

```
use app\SomeDAO;

class SomeTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $db;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=baseball;user=root;password=root";
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn);
    }
```

I'm getting an error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory.

How can I use PDO here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unix based (like linux, bsd, or OS X) systems, with MySQL `localhost` is secret code for try-to-use-a-socket, unless a you force it via a protocol flag to not do this (and no one ever does this).  Just remember `localhost` usually equals socket file.

If Mysql in your MAMP is running in non-socket mode, you can try replacing the host value with `127.0.0.1` which connects via TCP on via port to the local machine--you'll need to figure out which port it's running on if it's not the default port.

If you look at the MAMP start script

```
  less /Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh
```

You can see if it's starting in socket mode, and what file it's using if it has a config param like:

```
  --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

You can also investigate what open socket mysql might be using by following the answer in this question: [error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq/11990813#11990813)

If you're running in socket mode, you need to make sure PDO knows the path to the socket file.  One way to do this is specify the `unix_socket` instead of host in the dsn:

```
  $dsn =  "mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=baseball;user=root;password=root";
```

Comment: I'm believe I am running in socket mode because I can access pdo everywhere else with localhost. I tried the 127.0.0.1, but the connection was refused.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem like that at MAMP. My decided it, when I connected with PDO I used next line code:

```
$this->pdo = new \PDO("mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;port=8889;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8", 'root', 'root');
```

Comment: I think that @krisacorn should check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903097/mocking-pdo-with-phpunit