# sqlacodegen - can't connect to database

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use `sqlacodegen` on my `database`.

```
sqlacodegen mysql://root:mypassword@localhost/database_name
```

However, I keep receiving this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

In my `flask` application however, I access this very same `database` with no issues.

The above file doesn't exist on my system so I went to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and changed the line:

```
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

to

```
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Not entirely sure if this was the correct thing to do.. however even after this change, the systems seems to still be trying to run from the original location.

Comment: Is that the correct socket file?

Comment: I was able to use this answer to solve my issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14719106/2268507

Answer (score 0):

you can just create a symbolic link at `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` to the lampp's mysql sock.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock/ /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

restart lampp's mysql

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stopmysql
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
```