# Error Processing Request: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: magento

There has been an error processing your request in my site anyone help me please for this problem?

```
a:4:{i:0;s:73:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)";i:1;s:3543:"#0 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/riotjeans_prod/deploy/releases/20150227123830/index.php(98): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option: 1**
Check if your mysql server working or not. This error is that it is not able to connect to mysql.

**Option 2:** 
Check database configuration in `local.xml` file.

```
 Location: app/etc/local.xml
```

**Option 3** Create a standalone connection file for mysql connection

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "P@ssword";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for support. mean database connection is not prospered?

Comment: Okay but my server is working proper and local.xml is also fine

Comment: coming below error  Connection failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: issue is on server mysql level. you can get solution for this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: but how to check live?

Comment: when i using $servername = "127.0.0.1"; then 'Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)'

Comment: No 127 IP will not work. you need to use localhost OR mysql server address if localhost not allowed

Comment: Ok when using localhost coming error      Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: then localhost is correct option. Just contact your server support with error

Comment: okay my my server is linode and i wandt create ticket for database?

Comment: Thank you sir for your help

Comment: linode reply me on my support ticket    'This type of deep troubleshooting would most likely require a developer to investigate further. Your developer or system administrator will need to review your MySQL configurations to ensure that the web-server is able to connect and access your MySQL database.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83830/discussion-between-suditi-in-and-pankaj-pareek).

Answer (score 0):

Clean all possible caches and delete var/cache. Check if U can connect from command line using data from local.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for help i solve this problem miss this file in server app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php but now i am facing my site only showing is header part can visit riotjeans.com