# cannot connect to mysql server through socket 'var run mysqld mysqld.sock on Ubuntu (Emma)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, emma

I'M getting this Error

```
cannot connect to mysql server through socket 'var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(2)
```

when I Click the mysql(Emma) localhost and I getting this error, and I [googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115292/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock) it but no use,And also given below command I tried but getting Error only.

```
 $ps ax | grep mysql
   4348 pts/5    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
 $sudo service mysql start
   Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 $sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
   [....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. failed!
```

What Should I do, can any one give me a suggestion

Comment: The error message says: "See `systemctl status mysql.service` for details". What's the output if you run `systemctl status mysql.service`?

Comment: yeah I use this command also **systemctl start mysql** , And the result is Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. @iblamefish

Answer (score 1):

I get the Answer for above the question

```
    1.sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-5.6
    2.sudo apt-get autoremove
    3.sudo apt-get autoclean
    4.sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
    5.sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
    6.sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
    7.sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7
    8.service mysql start
```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server)

It's working fine!

Comment: I got the following  errormysqld:  while installing 5.7
 Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
 mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
 Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
 Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
 dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  mysql-server-5.7