# Getting error while trying to query status of mysql

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to see if mysql is running. When I do:

```
 mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

I get:

```
connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

But when I do: `ps aux | grep mysql` I get a proper PID and the user that is running it.

Why does it give an error in the first case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq , hope it can help

Comment: how did you start mysql? and what does the `ps aux | grep mysql` output look like?