# Unable to access MySql server in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp

I have installed `XAMPP`, when I'm trying to open `mysql` by `sudo mysql -u root -p`, i am getting the below error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: I hope it will helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run