# Ubuntu: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, sockets, ubuntu, apache2, owncloud

I have a Ubuntu 14.04. server with LAMP installed where an Owncloud is running. I tried to install [paperwork](https://github.com/twostairs/paperwork/wiki/Installing-Paperwork-on-Ubuntu-14.10) which didn't work out but thats not the problem.

After restarting my server I tried to access my owncloud again but I am facing an internal server error. See following picture. 
[Owncloud error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQiBo.png)

I looked in the log /var/log/apache2/error.log and theres following phrase:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server during query' in ...
```

I tried to restart the mysql service but this error appears:

```
stop: Unknown instance:
start: Job failed to start
```

Then I tried to login to mysql with `mysql -u root -p` and follorwing error appears:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've looked for the sockets on the machine with `find / -type s` and the socket was there: `/run/mysqld/` .
I created a symbolic link and pasted it to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Unfortnutely nothing worked. After restarting again I can't find the socket anymore the output of `find / -type s` is:

```
/dev/log
/run/php5-fpm.sock
/run/udev/control
find: `/proc/977/task/977/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/977/task/977/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/977/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/977/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
```

**Update**

I've reinstalled the server so problem is over :D

Answer (score 4):

If you install lampp server, run mysql first

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
```

Then make "mysqld" directory in /var/run

```
cd /var/run
sudo mkdir mysqld
```

Link your mysql from lampp to /var/run/mysqld

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

run `mysql -u root -p` . hope may help you

Answer (score 0):

1. If you install LAMPP server, run MySQL first

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
```

2. Then make "mysqld" directory in /var/run

```
cd /var/run
sudo mkdir mysqld
```

3. Link your mysql from lampp to /var/run/mysqld

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

4. run MySQL

```
mysql -u root -p .
```

5. If MySQL fails with «mysql» not found, install:

```
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.7   
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.1
```

Answer (score -1):

There is any issues with the mysql services. Please try to restart mysql services and check the mysql error logs for more information

Comment: Yes I already tried to restart it but this appears.
`stop: Unknown instance:`
`start: Job failed to start`

Comment: /var/log/mysql/error.log 
And the folloring error.log.1.gz are empty