# Create docker image with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, docker, gitlab-ci

I have **php5.6-apache image** built on ubuntu and **mysql:5.6 image**. I want to create docker image from above two images so that I can use newly built image in **gitlab ci**. How can I do that? I am fairly new to docker and gitlab.

I tried following in gitlab, but didn't work.

```
image: viraths/php5.6-apache:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test

deps build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    DNSDOCK_ALIAS: localhost
  services:
    - mysql:5.6
  script:
    - export APPLICATION_ENV=test
    - if [ -f /.dockerinit ]; then export COMPOSER_HOME=/cache/composer; fi;
    - php -v
    - composer install --no-progress --no-interaction --prefer-dist
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
    expire_in: 1 week
  tags:
    - docker
```

I got following error when running composer install in gitlab ci.

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: are you using linux ?

Comment: @SoniVimal yes ubuntu willy

Comment: maybe helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: @SoniVimal thanks for the link. I tried that , but no luck.

Comment: another one is for try, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38?page=1&tab=active#tab-top

Comment: @SoniVimal I tried almost all of them. I think something wrong the way I use mysql in gitlab ci may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't configure the database properly. With your configuration mysql is available on host `mysql` and port `3306`. Instead your application is trying a local connection thru a unix socket. Configure the connection and all should work.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example.

Comment: No, I'm afraid I can't tell you how to change the configuration of an application I haven't seen. I guess you use Symfony so just follow the guide: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html Otherwise just grep for host.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. I just changed my parameters.yml.dist file as follows.

    parameters:
        database_host:     mysql
        database_port:     3306