# local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in ipage server how to fix it

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

I made a manually website in php. After upload on ipage server when I try to access admin page which is inside in admin folder it show me the error Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` (2).  Please tell me how do I fix it.

Comment: Please provide code for use to work with.

Comment: whihc type of code mysql code or any other

Comment: this is my domain artical-center.com

Comment: when i check this on XAMPP its work perfectly but after upload it on ipage server database title show but picture missing and when i want to access admin.php it show the message Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: please check this artical-center.com/admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)

Comment: no there show only localhost error and not much detail there i want to ask specific server on ipage is any extra config file need to be uploaded during website upload on live server

Comment: iPage have a live chat support maybe your question would be better asked there. As all you have provided in your question here is It works here but doesn't work there.

Comment: thanks i ask it there.