# Job for mysqld.service failed See "systemctl status mysqld.service"

Tags: mysql, linux, database, amazon-web-services

Console says

```
[root@ip-172-31-18-2 mysql]# service mysqld start
Starting mysqld (via systemctl):  Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with an error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

mysqld.service

```
[root@ip-172-31-18-2 mysql]# systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - SYSV: MySQL database server.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-02-18 20:59:17 IST; 36s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9925 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 18 20:59:16 ip-172-31-18-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: MySQL database server....
Feb 18 20:59:17 ip-172-31-18-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal mysqld[9925]: MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Feb 18 20:59:17 ip-172-31-18-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal mysqld[9925]: Starting mysqld:  [FAILED]
Feb 18 20:59:17 ip-172-31-18-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 18 20:59:17 ip-172-31-18-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: MySQL database server..
Feb 18 20:59:17 ip-172-31-18-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Feb 18 20:59:17 ip-172-31-18-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

What I have tried until now:

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cf

chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

/etc/init.d/mysqld start

 /etc/init.d/mysqld stop

systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

rebooted the server

Still no luck.

my.cnf file

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for a dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: You should read mysql log under `/var/log/mysql` (usually) to understand why it cannot start

Comment: I found solution here , read it https://stackoverflow.com/a/26460819/11430151

Answer (score 64):

This amazingly worked.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
/etc/init.d/mysql start
service mysql start
```

Comment: This is not working.   failed!roo:~# /etc/init.d/mysql start
root@thyroo:~#  mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

Comment: for those who are facing this error,  mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. 
After performing above steps, restart the system

Comment: Simple 'reboot now' did it for me :D

Answer (score 38):

I had the same error, the problem was because I no longer had disk space.
to check the space run this:

```
$ df -h
```

[image: disk space]

Then delete some files that you didn't need.

After this commands:

```
service mysql start
systemctl status mysql.service
mysql -u root -p
```

After entering with the root password verify that the mysql service was active

Comment: This exactly what happened to my vagrant machine so I bumped up the disk.

Comment: @juanitourquiza how do I delete the irrelevant files without breaking anything else

Comment: Hi, before you delete the files should be sure that this partition don’t have files of system for example etc, var.

Answer (score 24):

I met this problem today, and fix it with bellowed steps.

1, Check the log file `/var/log/mysqld.log`

```
tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log

 2017-03-14T07:06:53.374603Z 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
 2017-03-14T07:06:53.374614Z 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such file or directory
```

The log says that there isn't a file or directory `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

2, Create the directory `/var/run/mysqld`

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld/
```

3, Start the mysqld again `service mysqld start`, but still fail, check the log again `/var/log/mysqld.log`

```
2017-03-14T07:14:22.967667Z 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-03-14T07:14:22.967678Z 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
```

It saids permission denied.

4, Grant the permission to mysql
`chown mysql.mysql /var/run/mysqld/`

5, Restart the mysqld

```
# service mysqld restart
Restarting mysqld (via systemctl):                         [  OK  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the log-file `sudo cat /var/log/mysqld.log`. There I found a clear description of my individual problem (disc quota).

Comment: Thank you. I had to check through the MySQL error log file: `tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log`. For my case, I had a docker container running on the same process as MySQL. I had to stop the docker container process.

Answer (score 19):

These are the steps I took to correct this:

Back up your my.cnf file in /etc/mysql and remove or rename it

```
sudo mv /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.bak
```

Remove the folder /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ using

```
sudo rm -r /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Verify you don't have a my.cnf file stashed somewhere else (I did in my home dir!) or in /etc/alternatives/my.cnf use

```
sudo find / -name my.cnf
```

Now reinstall every thing

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

In case your syslog shows an error like "mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/'" create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d /etc/mysql/conf.d
```

Then the service should be able to start with sudo service mysql start.

I hope it work

Comment: will this also purge the data?

Comment: @hocuspocus31 yeah , It will delete the mysql database and whole data as well.

Answer (score 18):

In my particular case, the error was appearing due to missing `/var/log/mysql` with `mysql-server` package 5.7.21-1 on Debian-based Linux distro. Having ran `strace` and `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` ( which is what the `systemd` service actually runs), it became apparent that the issue was due to this:

```
2019-01-01T09:09:22.102568Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: No such file or directory
```

I've recently removed contents of several directories in `/var/log` so it was no surprise. The solution was to create the directory and make it owned by `mysql` user as in

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql
$ sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
```

Having done that I've happily logged in via `sudo mysql -u root` and greeted with the old and familiar `mysql>` prompt

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy you don't understand how God has used this answer to save me from double embarrassment today. Thanks. I'm very grateful.

Comment: Thanks man, I used Stacer system cleaner and removed my application logs :(
Also need to this for ``apache2`` folder

Comment: This fixed my issue, I deleted all my /var/log/* files and folder from my server, and apache2 and mysql couldn't restart because of this!

Comment: add this command at last "$ systemctl restart mysql"

Answer (score 7):

if your problem not fix, you can try check more problem.

maybe mysql crash , like this :

you can check log in

> `sudo cat /var/log/mysql/error.log`

or you check

> sudo ls /var/crash

Answer (score 5):

try

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql
```

then start your mysql service

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

Comment: Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

Answer (score 3):

the issue is with the "/etc/mysql/my.cnf". this file must be modified by other libraries that you installed. this is how it originally should look like:

```
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms,
# as designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301  USA

#
# The MySQL  Server configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
    
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked,
First of all,

1. I remove all the servers
2. remove the folders of MySQL
3. create conf.d

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge mysql-server\* mariadb-server\*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
sudo mkdir -p /etc/mysql/conf.d
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

**Note make sure to backup your data because these commands will erase all of your MySQL data.**

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue .

```
root@*******:/root >mysql -uroot -password
```

> mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be
> insecure. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server
> through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

```
I found ROOT FS was also full and then I killed below lock session . 
root@**********:/var/lib/mysql >ls -ltr
total 0
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 0 Sep  9 06:41 mysql.sock.lock
```

Finally Issue solved .

Answer (score 0):

1. open my.cnf and copy the `log-error` path
2. then check the permission for the copied log file using
   `$ ls -l /var/log/mysql.log`
3. if any log file permission may changed from mysql:mysql, please change the file permission to
   `$ chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql.log`
4. then restart the mysql server
   `$ service mysql restart || systemctl restart mysqld`

note: this kind of errors formed by the permission issues. all the mysql service start commands using the log file for writing the status of mysql. If the permission has been changed, the service can't be write anything into the log files. If it happens it will stopped to run the service

Answer (score 0):

remove any command of **"secure_file_priv"** in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** and restart mysql.
If you want to use a file in mysql, copy those files to the main folder.
The main folder is obtained this way : `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

Answer (score 0):

You can purge all mysql-related packages and reinstall them with the following commands:

```
PACKAGES="mysql-server mysql-community-server mysql-community-server-core mysql-client mysql-client mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core  mysql-common mysql-community-client-plugins php-mysql"
apt purge $PACKAGES
echo "any remaining installed packages:"
dpkg -l|grep ii|grep mysql
apt install --reinstall mysql-common
apt install $PACKAGES
```

If there are any remaining packages (apart from `mysql-core`), add those to your list

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to check on your docker containers, for me it was my docker has mysql running on the background.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to the server using SSH.
2. Stop the affected MySQL service and the service plesk-web-socket to prevent it from attempting to start MySQL:

   ```
   service mysql stop || service mariadb stop && service plesk-web-socket stop
   ```
3. Back up all the MySQL data storage files. By default, they are located in the directory `/var/lib/mysql/`.

   For example:

   ```
   cp -a /var/lib/mysql /root/mysql_backup
   ```
4. Add the parameter `innodb_force_recovery` to the section `[mysqld]` of the MySQL configuration file. This option allows starting MySQL service in the recovery mode and try creating dumps of databases.

   For example:

   ```
   vi /etc/my.cnf
   [mysqld]
   innodb_force_recovery = 2
   ```
5. Start the MySQL service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after hours the solution was for me:
Open this file `nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
#I use mysql service if you use mysqld service, type mysqld instead of mysql
[mysql]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Comment: It helped me to recover.

Please read carefully https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

U also need to look for /var/log/mysql/error.log for the reason. And u may need to drop the table causing the crash. Once u make changes then remove innodb_force_recovery = 1 and restart. In documentation, It comes in [mysqld]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was working for me. I noticed I hadn't got the mysql command line tool installed so installed that (tried running `mysql -u root` which failed) and also ran the steps in here https://linuxhint.com/change-mysql-root-password-ubuntu/ which oddly seemed to work. I wonder if skipping network checks temporarily flushed it and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

in my case,  the error was appearing due to the configuration file, i can prove it,this is the `/var/log/mysql/error.log` content：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0a2w.png)

that remind me check the error.log file when i meet the errror

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Solved as given below.
Use command :

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages|grep -i mysql
```

to check if SELinux policy is causing the issue. If so, first check if SELinux policy is enabled using command `#sestatus`. If it shows enabled, then disable it.
To disable:

1. `# vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux`
2. change 'SELINUX=enforcing' to 'SELINUX=disabled'
3. restart linux
4. check with `sestatus` and it should show "disabled"

Uninstall and reinstall mysql. It should be working.

Comment: That's like "Every now and then, I forget my password. What can I do?" – "Remove the password from your account and you'll be fine."

Answer (score -1):

Backup your config or data and reinstall mysql

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server
sudo apt purge mysql-server
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt remove dbconfig-mysql


sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql* -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then install it again.

That works here.

Answer (score -1):

i have got the same  "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. ERROR.
after repeated deinstallation and installation does not work at all.
but this one work well> https://linuxtut.com/en/5a5b0f46620ae1b27b10/

you just need to remove everything from my.cnf file except [mysqld] and start the server. this really work. but you might not have the password for root in that case skip-grant-tables and restart server in safe mode and use mysql and
update mysql.user set authentication_string=null where user='root' and then can alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'your_$$new_99pwd#';
then login to secure mode and then you can create new user.

Answer (score -1):

after having tested several solutions without success, the one that finally worked is the following:
you can load the default configuration of your apache server

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
sudo a2dissite my.conf
systemctl reload apache2
```

then reload the configuration for your website

```
sudo a2ensite my.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
systemctl reload apache2
```