# Mysql - Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: mysql, centos7, systemctl

I installed `mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm` in my `Centos 7` using this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7) successfully and I was trying to change my `datadir` using the following [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-centos-7). It worked fine till step 2 but at step 3 when i tried to start mysql using `sudo systemctl start mysqld` it gave me an error like this :

`Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

I have tried the following solutions:

- [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317139/job-for-mysqld-service-failed-see-systemctl-status-mysqld-service)
- [Second](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/job-for-mysqld-service-failed-see-systemctl-status-mysqld-service-journalctl-xe-tail-30-var-log-mysql-error-log)

But none of them seem to work for me. This is what my `/var/log/mysqld.log` file says :

```
2018-06-15T09:08:32.294452Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) initializing of server in progress as process 14593
2018-06-15T09:08:37.698910Z 5 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: 7Y8An3/,r?ww
2018-06-15T09:08:40.729296Z 0 [System] [MY-013170] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) initializing of server has completed
2018-06-15T09:08:43.257796Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 14695
2018-06-15T09:08:43.896289Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-06-15T09:08:43.936018Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.11'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2018-06-15T09:21:15.039285Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'validate password plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use validate_password component instead.
2018-06-15T09:21:16.575642Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

I am new to this.