# Failed to start MySQL Community Server

Tags: mysql

I have updated mysql-server(5.7 to 8.0) with this command :

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

And  after the install , I get this error :

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Log journalctl -xe :

```
-- L'unité (unit) mysql.service a commencé à démarrer.
juil. 18 13:49:03 reflex02.soeman.fr systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
juil. 18 13:49:03 reflex02.soeman.fr systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
juil. 18 13:49:03 reflex02.soeman.fr systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) mysql.service a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
```

I don't know how resolve this problem , I can't delete mysql , I have data in.

Comment: Hello have you see this topic ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317139/job-for-mysqld-service-failed-see-systemctl-status-mysqld-service

Comment: i remove the mysql-server with apt get remove and I install it again , it work  but I lose all my data , do you have an idea to update mysql 5.7 to 8.0 without losing data ?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql Workbench has this feature, good luck!

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html