# Having trouble trying to use MYSQL in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, linux

Guys i'm having some trouble with MYSQL, i tried solutions but still not finding the answers, so basically the problem is when i always try to start or restart the service the output give this answer:

```
"Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."
```

When i type "systemctl status mysql.service and "journalctl -xe", this is the output:

```
   mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-04-16 23:17:52 UTC; 12min ago
  Process: 670 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILU

Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exi
Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, sche
Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart c
Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quick
Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 23:17:52 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Now, journalctl -xe:

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 16 23:32:22 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quick
Apr 16 23:32:22 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 23:32:22 ny1.us.veepn.4nat.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317139/job-for-mysqld-service-failed-see-systemctl-status-mysqld-service

Comment: yes, i tried it, but it's not working

Comment: read the log in `/var/log/mysql/`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. You'll probably have better luck at dba.stackexchange.com.