# MYSQL and MYSQLD not start MySQL 5.7 enterprise version on CentOS7

Tags: mysql

I just install MySQL 5.7 enterprise version 5.7.1 commercial Client and then Install 5.7.1 commercial  server.
I didn't do any thing just restart CentOS 7 VM
when I try to start the service of mysql i got error
1st i Try to start service using
**service mysql start**
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysql.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
then i try the following command
**service mysqld start**
Starting mysqld (via systemctl):  Job for mysqld.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysqld.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. [FAILED].

I unInstall the MySQL and delete the folder where log and data files created and then reinstall MySQL then restart CentOS again same Issue.

Regards,
Saad

Comment: What do you see when you run `systemctl status mysqld.service`

Comment: mysqld.service - SYSV: MySQL database server.
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-06-17 08:15:17 EDT; 16h ago
Process: 8143 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld start (code=exited,status=1/FAILURE)

.localdomain mysqld[8143]: MySQL Daemon failed to st.
.localdomain mysqld[8143]: Starting mysqld:  [FAILED]
.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control pro.
.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: MySQL.
.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

Comment: You need to run `systemctl status mysqld.service -l` . It will show the entire output within truncating.

Comment: mysqld.service - SYSV: MySQL database server.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-06-18 01:31:16 EDT; 25min a                                                go
  Process: 2201 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: MySQL database server....
.localdomain mysqld[2201]: MySQL Daemon failed to start
.localdomain mysqld[2201]: Starting mysqld:  [FAILED]
.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control proces

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317139/job-for-mysqld-service-failed-see-systemctl-status-mysqld-service

Comment: Thanks chin, I found the solution i.e. 1. mkdir  /var/run/mysqld 2. chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld then start service . It works for me now. Orignal issue is due to centos 7. when i reboot it will delete that folder. I don't know why. if you have any idea please guide me