# Getting Error: mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. after installing docker

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I've installed MySQL-server on my ubuntu 21 system, when i try to start MySQL-Server im getting `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.` 
it was working fine before I installed docker and run a MySQL on it

systemctl status mysql.service

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-01-22 18:32:17 IST; 7min>
    Process: 19128 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=>
    Process: 19136 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 19136 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 13 (Permission denied)
        CPU: 313ms

Jan 22 18:32:17 Lenovo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restar>
Jan 22 18:32:17 Lenovo systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 22 18:32:17 Lenovo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too qu>
Jan 22 18:32:17 Lenovo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code>
Jan 22 18:32:17 Lenovo systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

journalctl -xeu mysql.service

```
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 6908 and the job result is done.
Jan 22 18:32:17 Lenovo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too qu>
Jan 22 18:32:17 Lenovo systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code>
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code>
Jan 22 18:32:17 Lenovo systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 6908 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: What does `systemctl status mysql.service`  and `journalctl -xeu mysql.service` shows ? How did you start mysql , `service mysqld start` or `service mysql start` ?

Comment: i started with service mysql start

Comment: Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317139/job-for-mysqld-service-failed-see-systemctl-status-mysqld-service)

Answer (score 15):

I tried this and it worked:

```bash
sudo apt autoremove --purge mysql-server\* mariadb-server\*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
sudo mkdir -p /etc/mysql/conf.d
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

**Note:** make sure to **backup your data**, because these commands will erase all of your **MySQL** data.

Comment: worked for Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 3):

Try these commands

```
sudo mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cf

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

sometimes for some systems, when you give the below two commands it will show **Not a directory** if it shows cut the below two commands off and follow the next command.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start

/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

Finally, try this command

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

After the *systemctl restart* the system will hang and log out sometimes. If it logged out, log in again and

Run `sudo systemctl start mysql.service` it will work fine.

For further commands check the link [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/sql/Job+for+mysql.service+failed+because+the+control+process+exited+with+error+code.+See+%22systemctl+status+mysql.service%22+and+%22journalctl+-xe%22+for+details.) and check following commands on that website if above doesn't work for you

Comment: Not worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error for the Digitalocean Ubuntu droplet. The problem was I was using a 500MB RAM Droplet, and 500MB RAM was not enough to install the MySQL server. So I resized the droplet to 1GB RAM and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I try same and got this:

```
systemctl status mysql.service
× mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-10-17 22:38:59 CEST; 1min 40s ago
    Process: 17421 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 8ms

Okt 17 22:38:59 install-web systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Okt 17 22:38:59 install-web systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Okt 17 22:38:59 install-web systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Okt 17 22:38:59 install-web systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 17 22:38:59 install-web systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I have reinstalled but that didn't help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32966833)

Answer (score 0):

i tried below commands and issue resolved

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge mysql-server\* mariadb-server\*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
sudo mkdir -p /etc/mysql/conf.d
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Comment: Dont try this. this will remove all your data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is adding swap to your server you are using. Cause basic 500mb or 1gb packages cannot run MySQL smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I come to post my solution. Apparently, there were some processes keeping mysql busy. I had to stop mysql with `sudo service mysql stop`, then run `ps aux | grep mysql`

```
    root@backend:~# ps aux | grep mysql
root     3036117  0.0  0.1  11900  3788 ?        S    08:53   0:00 sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking
root     3036118  0.0  0.0  11900   112 ?        Ss   08:53   0:00 sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking
root     3036119  0.0  0.0   2892  1528 ?        S    08:53   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking
mysql    3037396  1.4 21.6 1753988 438740 ?      Sl   09:17   0:23 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
root     3038431  0.0  0.1   7008  2172 pts/2    S+   09:45   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

and kill all the mysql processes using `sudo kill -9 <pid>`. After that, I started mysql again `sudo service mysql start` and the problem was solved.

NOTE: The origin of my problem came from the attempt to init mysql with this command `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking` and tried to cancel it using Ctrl+C before the process ended.