# Getting error while installing phpmyadmin in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: phpmyadmin

Getting error when installing phpmyadmin in ubuntu 14.04

I ran below 2 commands for installing it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

During installation I selected apache and gave administrators password and phpmyadmin password then got the following error.

[image: Error Snapshot]

Comment: Probably already answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11990813/7802808](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11990813/7802808)

Comment: its actually a fresh installation in a new system in azure. There isn't any mysql or any other softwares installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like phpmyadmin tries to auto-configure connection to local mysql-server during the installation. But one of the steps of installation asks if you want to configure database immediately or to do it later manually (see attached [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2v6v.png)).

So, if you'd like to use local mysql-server, you need to install it first, but if you want to configure connection to some remote mysql-server, skip automatic configuration and do it later manually.

Comment: give me some time i am installing mysql-server and trying it now

Comment: I installed mysql-server first and then phpmyadmin so it worked.   Thanks @Andrii