# Pythonanywhere MySQL - Access denied

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere

When I try to do:

```
"drop database wachtwoorden;"
```

I get the message:

> -ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'Jip1912'@'%' to database 'wachtwoorden'-

So I tried in bash:

```
"mysql -u root -p"
```

I had to give a password and after that I got:

> -ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)-

Comment: For the first one, does the user Jip1912 have the DROP privilege?  If not, the drop will fail. See this:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop  The other sounds like a separate issue, like the mysql daemon is not running, or the may be permission issues. See this for various things to check:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: No I dont have that privilege, otherwise it would work, but an hour ago it just worked...When I run sudo find / -type s, it returns "sudo: unknown user: root
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin". I made the database and I didn't even know that I could add people or something so I don't understand that I don't have the privileges anymore, an hour ago I did had them ...

Comment: Do you know root's password?     What if you try to login by doing:  `mysql -u Jip1912 -p` ?  Other than that, it almost sounds like something bad has happened. Were more things deleted unexpectedly?

Comment: When I do mysql -u Jip1912 -p, it says Enter password:, I typ the password and it says 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2). In case I fill in the wrong password, the password is the one right here https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/static/images/flask-tutorial-databases-tab-empty.png, right? 
What do you mean by something bad? It doesn't really matter if the database gets deleted because im just testing things and I want to delete the database myself.

Comment: Maybe something bad, I'm not sure, only how it sounds based on your description.  Can you check that the mysqld is running?

Comment: How do I do that? But what is an example of something bad?

Comment: Sounds bad: "unable to initialize policy plugin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have drop privileges for your databases on PythonAnywhere, you're just not using the right database name. Your databases are listed on the databases page.

Comment: Man...... thanks... a lot.. I am soooooo stupid. Ofcourse I had to do ''drop database Jip1912$wachtwoorden;... I thought it worked before the way I did but that is certainly not the case.....and I was trying to get it work the whole evening but I only had to do this.. Thanks.