# 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' in debian6

Tags: linux, sockets, debian, mysql-cluster

Well, recently I tried to install `mysql_cluster` on debian6. At first it works well, but when I try to install `mysql_cluster` multiply, an error occurs saying, that I cannot login as root anymore. I was trying to modify the `pwd` of `root` with the command:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password '654321'
```

But it turned out with wrong info as:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
```

I tried everything I can to solve this problem but failed. I was attemped to run the command:

```
find / -name *.sock -type s
```

but I just cannot find the file `mysqld.socks` anywhere. As reference I had tried every method from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq).

All the methods failed, that I've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)