# /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock does not exist when I install Bitnami (lamp server)

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a problem, I want to work on symfony, linux, I try to install lamp (bitnami), when I run the application I will have (No such file or directory), I looked for that, I found that apparently the problem does not come from symfony itself but Mysql, suddenly when I run (mysql -u root -p) I will have the error that tells me that the socket does not is not that basic, in (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock/), but I was surprised when I went to the folder (run / ..) I found the mysqld folder and of course the file mysqld.sock.
well I redid the installation of everything and before installing lamp there's no problem the file is in this place (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock) exists beautifully, but as soon as the installation bitnami finishes no trace of this file, can you explain me please,

I want to learn symfony, beh the I almost despair.

Answer (score 1):

(/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock/) is a temp file created on database startup and deleted on stop. The reason it doesn't exist is because the database is not starting.

**Most common reason:**

Your drive is full. Check your backup dumpfile hasnt filled the OS drive that sql is trying to start on.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is already tackled here. have you tried this one sir ? [error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)