# Can't connect to MySQL server from localhost but MySQL service is running

Tags: mysql, windows-10, localhost, port, mysql-workbench

No matter what I try i keep getting this error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061).

This goes for: 1) >mysql 2) >mysql -u root 3) >mysql -u root -p 4) >mysqlshow etc....

```
Mysql version: 8.0.12.0
OS: Windows 10
```

So the suggested solution I keep encountering is to enable the mysql service manually, but the mysql80 service is running no problem and the port 3307 (i tried both the default `3306 and 3307`) show up in netstat as:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:3307           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I don't see anything wrong in my `my.ini file` either (skip-=networking= is commented out and there is no bind-address line), but just in case here is a link: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1udfXwvl-W7UI3pCissTTBYD0wNnDTBiT/view?usp=sharing`.

> mysqld -u root --skip-grant-tables
>   Doesn't do anything at all, no error messages either.

I disabled firewall as well but still no luck.

I've been looking for a solution for days on end now so any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: to clarify I cannot access the sql shell via the command line, because this also gives me ERROR 2003

Comment: Did you enable remote access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: So how do I run the sql command "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION" if i cant login to sql via cmd

Comment: Also this is not a remote connection

Comment: open your console and: `mysql`, and add the output here

Comment: Did you specify the port on the command line? Since 3307 is not the default the command will try

Comment: just typing sql in cmd gives me the same error : ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: specifying the port gave me the same error as well

Comment: how i fixed it in linux.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60557989/7300865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i finally got it to work, I don't know where the issue was but this is what I did:

1) stop the mysql80 service and delete it with Sc delete MySQ in the cmd

2) Go to Add or remove programs and uninstall anything mysql related

3) remove the mysql folders in Program files, programData and C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming

4) download sql community installer and when asked if you want to download the latest installer **DON'T** download it, just use the current one. Previous clean re-installs didn't work until I stopped using this newer installer version.

5) Reinstall everything as before

6) SUCCES!

Answer (score 0):

After stopping firewall restart system and check. Run the cmd as Administrator and check. Please paste the error log for more clarity.