# Laravel artisan migrate crashes database

Tags: mysql, laravel, artisan-migrate

I created a migration for a table which **has over 2 million records**. migration is adding a new column to that table as follow.I am **using vagrant** as my **environment**.

```
Schema::table('tb_selection', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->tinyInteger('retired_flag')->after('display_flag')->default(0);
        });
```

when i ran `php artisan migrate`, it keeps still and doing nothing. then it throws error

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

then i checked my database and it is crashed. no tables were there. i had to import the DB again. what can be the solution for this?

Comment: did you run the php artisan migrate command while connected to ssh?

Comment: You can check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq) for help

Comment: You need to check mysql error logs to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Please do check you started mysql service: "sudo service mysql start" without quotes

Comment: @kapitan yes mate

Comment: @DPS tried but it gives error error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'