# ERROR 2002 (HY000): can't login to mysql with standard sintax

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I don't know why standard login to **mysql** fails:

> mysql -u davide -p Enter password: "my password" ERROR 2002 (HY000):
>   Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I can log in with this command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u davide -p
```

I can't login via **phpMyadmin** too for this reason

Comment: Check that your server is running and that it's not logging any errors in the `mysql.log` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' -- Missing /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)