# Connect to MySQL container from the host using command line

Tags: mysql, docker

I have started Mysql instance in docker by issuing command `docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret some-mysql` . But when i am trying to login as root by issuing command `mysql -u root -p` and giving password superscret . I am getting below provided error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' -- Missing /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)

Comment: did you check the container logs? did it start smoothly?

Comment: superscret != supersecret

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are executing `mysql -u root -p` from the host itself  not inside the container.

So based on my assumption the container does not have a mysql.sock inside the host itself when you run it, so you need to change the default protocol.

This command will connect through `tcp` instead of socket

```
mysql --protocol=tcp -u root -p
```