# Connecting to MySQL without pw - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sockets

I have a Wordpress website that used to work fine, but recently I received the message "Error establishing a database connection" when trying to navigate to it. Upon researching online, I realized it may be related to changing my db password.

So I am following instructions on resetting the Mysql pw from here - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password.

Steps:

`sudo systemctl stop mysql`

`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`

Output:

```
2019-08-25T15:23:22.702830Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-08-25T15:23:22.707805Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-08-25T15:23:22.712056Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

I then do:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

and then run 
`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`

Output

```
2019-08-25T15:33:49.404761Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-08-25T15:33:49.411891Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-08-25T15:33:49.443922Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2019-08-25T15:33:49.992471Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

From here, I do `mysql -u root`, and see this

Output:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**Troubleshooting done so far**

To troubleshoot, I followed the suggestions [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) to find the sock file. I tried to do by by

`sudo find / -type s` to find the `mysql.sock` file, but do not find it in the list.

Output:

```
/run/acpid.socket
/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
/run/snapd-snap.socket
/run/snapd.socket
/run/uuidd/request
/run/user/0/systemd/private
/run/user/0/systemd/notify
/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
/run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
/run/systemd/journal/dev-log
/run/systemd/journal/socket
/run/systemd/journal/stdout
/run/systemd/journal/syslog
/run/systemd/private
/run/systemd/notify
/run/udev/control
/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
/var/spool/postfix/private/proxywrite
/var/spool/postfix/private/relay
/var/spool/postfix/private/ifmail
/var/spool/postfix/private/retry
/var/spool/postfix/private/defer
/var/spool/postfix/private/maildrop
/var/spool/postfix/private/mailman
/var/spool/postfix/private/discard
/var/spool/postfix/private/anvil
/var/spool/postfix/private/scalemail-backend
/var/spool/postfix/private/bsmtp
/var/spool/postfix/private/bounce
/var/spool/postfix/private/verify
/var/spool/postfix/private/trace
/var/spool/postfix/private/uucp
/var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp
/var/spool/postfix/private/local
/var/spool/postfix/private/error
/var/spool/postfix/private/rewrite
/var/spool/postfix/private/proxymap
/var/spool/postfix/private/smtp
/var/spool/postfix/private/tlsmgr
/var/spool/postfix/private/scache
/var/spool/postfix/private/virtual
/var/spool/postfix/public/showq
/var/spool/postfix/public/qmgr
/var/spool/postfix/public/pickup
/var/spool/postfix/public/cleanup
/var/spool/postfix/public/flush
/var/spool/postfix/dev/log
```

I tried to restart the server by `sudo service mysql start` but got this output

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The output for `systemctl status mysql.service` is

```
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-08-25 15:41:53 UTC; 27s ago
  Process: 16974 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16966 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
 Main PID: 16974 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 16975 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 5.1M
      CPU: 331ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─16975 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─17042 sleep 1

Aug 25 15:41:53 keshinpoint systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 25 15:41:53 keshinpoint systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/F
```

The output for `journalctl -xe` is

```
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 25 21:08:08 keshinpoint systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Aug 25 21:08:08 keshinpoint audit[7730]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/
Aug 25 21:08:08 keshinpoint audit[7730]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/
Aug 25 21:08:08 keshinpoint audit[7730]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/
Aug 25 21:08:08 keshinpoint kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1566767288.456:105247): apparmor="DENIED
Aug 25 21:08:08 keshinpoint kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1566767288.460:105248): apparmor="DENIED
Aug 25 21:08:08 keshinpoint kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1566767288.460:105249): apparmor="DENIED
Aug 25 21:08:08 keshinpoint systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/F
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling resta
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel


-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint audit[7815]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/7815/status" pid=7815 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1566767318.940:105250): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/7815/status" pid=7815 comm="mysqld" requested_m
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint audit[7815]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=7815 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint audit[7815]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/7815/status" pid=7815 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1566767318.948:105251): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=7815 comm="mysqld" req
Aug 25 21:08:38 keshinpoint kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1566767318.948:105252): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/7815/status" pid=7815 comm="mysqld" requested_m
Aug 25 21:08:39 keshinpoint systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 25 21:08:44 keshinpoint kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=8e:96:82:1a:cc:9e:5c:45:27:78:fb:30:08:00 SRC=81.22.45.100 DST=174.138.62.216 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=245 ID=10892 PROTO=TCP SPT=4071
Aug 25 21:08:47 keshinpoint kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=8e:96:82:1a:cc:9e:5c:45:27:78:fb:30:08:00 SRC=51.81.7.101 DST=174.138.62.216 LEN=40 TOS=0x14 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=36258
Aug 25 21:08:53 keshinpoint sshd[7855]: Invalid user www from 51.38.186.228
Aug 25 21:08:53 keshinpoint sshd[7855]: input_userauth_request: invalid user www [preauth]
Aug 25 21:08:53 keshinpoint sshd[7855]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Aug 25 21:08:53 keshinpoint sshd[7855]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=51.38.186.228
Aug 25 21:08:56 keshinpoint sshd[7855]: Failed password for invalid user www from 51.38.186.228 port 60446 ssh2
```

Feels like a rabbit hole here. Can someone please help me with this? I would be grateful for any guidance offered, as Ive tried answers from multiple stackoverflow posts.