# MySQL community server suddenly stopped working

Tags: mysql

MySQL community server unable to start after some days of installation in Ubuntu 18.04, I reinstall it and it start working fine but after some time it again raises same issue.

But when I reinstated it, it worked but after some time it fails to start. 
Really confused about that...

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq