# job for mysqld.service failed

Tags: mysql, linux, nginx

Unable to start mysql or mysqld.

Console says:

```
 (base) root@X-Public-Server:/# systemctl status mysql.service
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
(base) root@ELC-Public-Server:/# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: deactivating (final-sigterm) since Fri 2022-04-22 00:31:18 UTC; 25min ago
  Process: 2349 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 2317 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31447 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 13 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─2352 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Apr 22 00:56:47 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...

(base) root@X-Public-Server:/# systemctl status mysqld.service
Unit mysqld.service could not be found.


(base) root@ELC-Public-Server:~# systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
(base) root@ELC-Public-Server:~#
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstall mysql, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq).

Also tried checking if the socket file mysql.sock is saved elsewhere, but it does not exist anywhere in the system server.

Ran journalctl -u mysql.service --since=today in the console to see status:

```
(base) root@ELC-Public-Server:/var/log/mysql# journalctl -u mysql.service --since=today
-- Logs begin at Wed 2022-04-20 18:27:15 UTC, end at Fri 2022-04-22 03:29:32 UTC. --
Apr 22 00:00:01 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 22 00:00:02 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 22 00:00:03 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Apr 22 00:00:05 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Apr 22 00:00:09 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 22 00:00:09 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 22 00:00:10 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Apr 22 00:00:12 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Apr 22 00:00:16 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 22 00:00:16 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 22 00:00:17 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Apr 22 00:00:19 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Apr 22 00:00:23 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 22 00:00:23 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 22 00:00:24 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Apr 22 00:00:26 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Apr 22 00:00:30 ELC-Public-Server systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

Also tried starting mysql.service:

```
(base) root@ELC-Public-Server:/var/log/mysql# systemctl start mysql.service
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Update: systemctl start mysql.service works; but mysql.service deactivates automatically. Here's my var/log/mysql/error.log:

```
2022-04-22T03:35:58.039614Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more$2022-04-22T03:35:58.041968Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 20061 ...
2022-04-22T03:35:58.047273Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2022-04-22T03:35:58.047301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-04-22T03:35:58.047306Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-04-22T03:35:58.047310Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2022-04-22T03:35:58.047314Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-04-22T03:35:58.047319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-04-22T03:35:58.047711Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-04-22T03:35:58.047839Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2022-04-22T03:35:58.050070Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-04-22T03:35:58.060577Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-04-22T03:35:58.063670Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-04-22T03:35:58.075860Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.090044Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-04-22T03:35:58.090185Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-04-22T03:35:58.128613Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.129577Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.129596Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.130151Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.37 started; log sequence number 8384821
2022-04-22T03:35:58.130435Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-04-22T03:35:58.130746Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.133352Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220422  3:35:58
2022-04-22T03:35:58.138354Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.138378Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.138384Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.138388Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.138996Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.139035Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.139143Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2022-04-22T03:35:58.139163Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2022-04-22T03:35:58.139206Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2022-04-22T03:35:58.147643Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2022-04-22T03:35:58.147842Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2022-04-22T03:36:00.497947Z 0 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2022-04-22T03:36:00.497989Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2022-04-22T03:36:02.498125Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 1 remaining clients
2022-04-22T03:36:02.498191Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 2  user: 'treasure-hunt'

2022-04-22T03:36:02.498296Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2022-04-22T03:36:02.498583Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2022-04-22T03:36:02.499112Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2022-04-22T03:36:02.499123Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2022-04-22T03:36:02.499127Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2022-04-22T03:36:02.499146Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2022-04-22T03:36:02.499152Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2022-04-22T03:36:02.499155Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2022-04-22T03:36:02.499196Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2022-04-22T03:36:02.499201Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
```

Comment: `mysqld.service` != `mysql.service`. IT, its all about attention to detail.

Comment: Yes @danblack. Neither mysqld nor mysql are working for me. How do i fix it??

Comment: `systemctl status mysql.service` showing it `deactivating`. So for some reason doing a slow (25min+) shutdown. The mysql.socket is one of the first things removed on shutdown. Use `journalctl -u mysql.service --since=today` to see what is going on. Edit this info into your question if you have troubles. `systemctl start mysql.service` will start it, or should. Hard to say the state of the install when a 10year old uninstall/reinstall was followed.

Comment: @danblack thanks for the suggestion! I updated the question with the console logs