# How do I get rid of error 2002 after installing MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, backend, web-development-server

I'm fairly new to the world of web development.

I'm working on a page that requires a database and I followed a tutorial on YouTube in reference to MySQL. However, after I followed the information I attempted to login with my password that I had just set and now I'm getting an error message

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

How do I get rid of this and access MySQL? Also, I already have PHP (from VS CODE) installed and XAMPP, those are working fine.

-PS I'm using MacOS

Comment: Check my.ini for allowed connecting channels. uncomment `socket=..` in [mysqld].

Comment: Check this link out. Might get you on the right track. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq