# Uninstall MySQL in WSL

Tags: mysql, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I uninstall MySQL in WSL?

I have version 5.7.4 installed. After reading over the changes for upgrading to the latest 5.7.x version so I could upgrade to 8.0 (there's a [minimum requirement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html) of 5.7.9 to upgrade to 8.0), I figured it would be easier to just uninstall MySQL and start over (I have nothing worth saving from playing around with it previously).

I tried running the following commands (as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql) and [this one](https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/how-to-uninstall-mysql/)) and got the following responses:

```
$ sudo apt remove mysql mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql
```

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge *mysql*
zsh: no matches found: *mysql*
```

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
zsh: no matches found: mysql-server-core-*
```

After running those, I'm still able to start and stop my server with the following commands (note that these are not necessarily the usual systemd commands because I'm in WSL2):

- `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`
- `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`

Unsure if this is relevant, but even when the server is running I'm not seeing the socket when I enter `sudo find / -type s` as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990813/12406158).

I'm wondering it'd be okay to just delete what files I can find manually, but that seems like a bad idea

- /var/lib/mysql/
- /usr/share/mysql/
- /usr/lib/mysql/

Comment: If you do a `*mysql*`, you ask the shell to replace this pattern by the list of files matching the pattern. Not surprisingly there is no such a file. What happens afterwards, depends on how you have configured your shell, and of course this can mean that your bash and your zsh behave differently. For instance I have configured my shell so that in this case it spits out an error message and aborts, because this is the behaviour I **want** to have.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was using zsh as a shell. I successfully removed MySQL with `sudo apt-get remove --purge '*mysql*'`

Comment: Kind of funny I was having the exact same problem in Mysql 8.0. I had to disable the .service, reload the systemd daemon and then kill the process before being able to remove it.