# Can't start mysql server

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

After rebooting server, I can't start mysql again

I received this message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I tried **journalctl -xe** and received this

```
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 06 21:25:57 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 06 21:25:57 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 21:25:57 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 06 21:25:57 myserver systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 06 21:25:57 myserver systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Nov 06 21:25:58 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

here is the result for **systemctl status mysql.service**

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-11-06 21:29:00 UTC; 21s ago
  Process: 4563 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4560 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4563 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 4566 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 320.0K
      CPU: 400ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─4566 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─4625 sleep 1

Nov 06 21:29:00 myserver systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Nov 06 21:29:01 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Please help ! Thank you!

Comment: What does "reseting the ubuntu server" mean?

Comment: @Arkascha i meant rebooting*

Comment: Have you checked the log file i.e `/var/log/mysql/error.log`?

Comment: For Ubuntu people: the file location is: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 7):

I found out the solution after checking mysql error.log

The disk was full.