# Django cannot parse POST parameters of WSGIRequest on Internal Server Errors

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework and all the API calls come from Android and iOS apps. The system works perfectly most of the time, however, when an internal server error happens and I get an email from Django, the `POST` of the `WSGIRequest` contains `<could not parse>` instead of the actual posted JSON data (even though `'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json'` is also in the header, and the data is sent as JSON).

This is really annoying, as it would be great to see the request body that actually causes the error, not just the stacktrace.

The `<could not parse>` part is *very* similar to this question (in the `ModPythonRequest` part): [django request.POST contains <could not parse>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257618/django-request-post-contains-could-not-parse), except the actual problem is slightly different. Also the reference link in that question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471661/mod-python-could-not-parse-the-django-post-request-for-blackberry-and-some-andro) seems to have gone down, even though the name looked very promising.

I'm on Django 1.6.2 and DRF 2.3.13.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `POST` dictionary of the `WSGIRequest` is always going to be invalid, because it is intended to hold the parsed form data when the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

The data you want is in the `body` attribute of the `WSGIRequest` object, which isn't output when that object is converted to a string to be written to the log.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer, I think. However, turns out it's quite a bit of work to actually get the `body` written to the error report that gets sent. Still haven't figured it out fully...

Answer (score 5):

When using Django REST framework, you will typically want to access `request.DATA` (which will handle whatever formats you have parsers configured for - defaulting to form content and JSON) instead of Django's standard `request.POST`, which will only handle form encoded data.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I remembered that but then completely missed it!