# Http request with multiple files is not able to read by django server

Tags: android, python, django, apache, multifile-uploader

I am trying to send multiple files(images and audio) from an android device using `MultipartEntityBuilder` (java) with http request. Everytime request including files reaches server and is working as expected but sometimes(10%) django server is not able to read the content of the request.

After going through all the links related to this problem, I come to know that this problem may happen because of the **broken request** That is if someone cancelled the request in between.

As my request is an `AsyncTask` to the request should not break.

> I know this question is already asked. As I didn't get a proper solution from these posts, I want to reopen the issue. So instead of making this as `duplicate`,please try to give me some light.

Links: -

- [django UnreadablePostError: request data read error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544124/django-unreadableposterror-request-data-read-error)
- [IOError: request data read error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823280/ioerror-request-data-read-error/7089413)

Server Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/prototype/version1/views.py", line 2515, in manage_app_data
    print request.FILES
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 165, in _get_files
    self._load_post_and_files()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 215, in _load_post_and_files
    self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 180, in parse_file_upload
    return parser.parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 140, in parse
    for item_type, meta_data, field_stream in Parser(stream, self._boundary):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 598, in __iter__
    for sub_stream in boundarystream:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 473, in next
    return type(self).__next__(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 415, in __next__
    return LazyStream(BoundaryIter(self._stream, self._boundary))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 441, in __init__
    unused_char = self._stream.read(1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 315, in read
    out = b''.join(parts())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 308, in parts
    chunk = next(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 473, in next
    return type(self).__next__(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 330, in __next__
    output = next(self._producer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 473, in next
    return type(self).__next__(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 391, in __next__
    data = self.flo.read(self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 244, in read
    six.reraise(UnreadablePostError, UnreadablePostError(*e.args), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 242, in read
    return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 51, in read
    result = self.buffer + self._read_limited(size - len(self.buffer))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 39, in _read_limited
    result = self.stream.read(size)
UnreadablePostError: request data read error
```

How to fix ? what is going wrong?